# Deeplinking Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

My deep linking works perfectly if I tap the link from any other application.

But if I copy paste the link to Chrome then try to open it application does not start. Only the html content is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />`
to your intent filter?

From Android developers [source](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html):

> `<category>` 
>   Include the BROWSABLE category. The BROWSABLE category is
>   required in order for the intent filter to be accessible from a web
>   browser. Without it, clicking a link in a browser cannot resolve to
>   your app.